# DirectX11 - Textures and dynamic changes

Tags: dynamic, textures, directx-11

I have a few questions about DirectX 11.

When I create texture via CreateTexture2D and I specify DEFAULT usage I should be able to use UpdateSubresource, right?

a) Does the memory update must be in the same format as the original texture? I mean when I CreateTexture with DDS DXT1, does the UpdateSubresource data have to be DDS DXT1 too?

b) When is it possible to update resource? In DX12 you can update resoruce before you finish command list. Otherwise nothing happens.

c) I should update each mip with update where each index of subresource is index*miplevels, right?

Or should I use map unmap instead? Is there any good example with all the rules that are necessary for sucessful update?

Answer (score 4):

This most efficient method for loading a texture is to use `initData` when you create it. You can make it `DEFAULT` or `IMMUTABLE`.

The other approach is to use `DEFAULT` textures and a smaller set of `STAGING` textures. You load your data into the `STAGING` textures via `Map` and then copy via `CopyResource`. Ideally you reuse `STAGING` textures (same size, mips, format, etc.). `UpdateSubresource` works, but is not as efficient--it's most often used for Constant Buffers.

Dynamic textures are really only for things you plan to update every frame or every few frames. Depending on the hardware, they are put into slightly less efficient (for rendering) memory that the GPU and CPU can both access.

Use the helper `D3D11CalcSubresource` defined in `d3d11.h` to figure out the subresource:

```
UINT D3D11CalcSubresource( UINT MipSlice, UINT ArraySlice, UINT MipLevels )
{
    return MipSlice + ArraySlice * MipLevels;
}
```

This is covered on MSDN in the *Programming Guide*:

[How to: Initialize a Texture Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476905.aspx)
[How to: Use dynamic resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn508285.aspx)

See also [DDSTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/DDSTextureLoader.cpp) and [WICTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/WICTextureLoader.cpp)

> Note that you can get some sense of how inefficient `UpdateSubresource` is by taking a look at the DirectX 12 helper that implements that functionality [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Libraries/D3DX12/d3dx12.h).

Comment: I was actually doing task to project, where my goal was to replace all textures with different in existing DX11 app. So I had to hook different DirectX methods.

Comment: Your answer is contradictory. On the one hand you say that dynamic resources/textures are very inefficient (using Map/Unmap). On the other you say UpdateSubresource is very inefficient which is meant to be used with _USAGE_DEFAULT textures. But why create a staging texture in the first place. I did it by creating a _USAGE_DEFAULT texture and simply change it at will during runtime by using `UpdateSubresource` and `D3D11CalcSubresource`. Of course this is only efficient for textures you don't plan on changing every frame or so (in which case you should use _USAGE_DYNAMIC) - as you mentioned.

Comment: ``UpdateSubresource`` is creating the equivalent of a staging texture in the background. It's the creation/destruction of resources that is relatively expensive. There's also a penalty for having the textures in memory you can access from the CPU (except on UMA architectures).

Answer (score 1):

So what I found including my solution:

If the texture is created as `DYNAMIC` you can't `Map` it if it has more than one mips. (I had more mips in my textures so I had to do it other way)

So I had to go with `DEFAULT` textures on creation. Then `UpdateSubresource` and `D3D11CalcSubresource` in for loop where I updated all mips in the texture. So in my case with simple multi mip-map 2D textures: `D3D11CalcSubresource( i, 0, totalMipsInTexture)`. I managed to update the textures before `Present` was called (beware of multithreading).

My final recommendation: if you struggle, enable debug layer in DirectX (when you create device pass). It will tell you what are you doing wrong.